# Ajax with 2 drop down menus

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have 2 drop down menus. After a user has selected an option from each I wish for an answer to be generated by AJAX. I can do this with just one drop down using the example found here:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

I have followed some suggestions to try and modify the script for 2 dropdowns, however I have been unsuccessful. It seems that the data is not being posted to the getuser.php page.

My HTML code page is as follows:

```
<?php
  require('includes/application_top.php');
?>

<!doctype html public "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUser(current_size, current_shoe)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?size="+current_size"&shoe="current_shoe);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

   <?php
    $query = "SELECT products_name, products_shoe_size FROM products_description WHERE language_id = 1 and products_shoe_size != '' ";
    // Execute it, or return the error message if there's a problem.
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    ?>

   <form> 
        <?php

        $dropdown = "<select name='current_shoe' id='current_shoe'><option value=''>Select the model of your current shoes:</option>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row['products_shoe_size']}'>{$row['products_name']}</option>";
    }
    $dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";
    echo $dropdown;

    ?>

 <select name="current_size" id="current_size" onchange="showUser(Document.getElementById('current_size').value, Document.getElementById('current_shoe').value)">
<option value="">Select the size of your current shoes:</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="2.5">2.5</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="3.5">3.5</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="4.5">4.5</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="5.5">5.5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="6.5">6.5</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="7.5">7.5</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="8.5">8.5</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="9.5">9.5</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="10.5">10.5</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="11.5">11.5</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="12.5">12.5</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
</select>

</form>

<br />
<div id="txtHint"><b>Sizing info will be listed here.</b></div>

</body>
</html> 
  <?php require(DIR_WS_INCLUDES . 'application_bottom.php'); ?>
```

I'm guessing that the problem can be found in one of these lines of code:

```
function showUser(current_size, current_shoe)

xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?size="+current_size"&shoe="current_shoe);

 <select name="current_size" id="current_size" onchange="showUser(Document.getElementById('current_size').value, Document.getElementById('current_shoe').value)">
```

If anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong I will be eternally grateful. I'm fast running out of hair.

Comment: Doesn't the return in if (str == "") { return you every single time you call showUser? Never executing the rest of your code?

Comment: I realize this comment doesn't answer your question, but you will save yourself a great deal of time by using a javascript library like jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, when you call the `showUser` function in the change event handler, you need to use `document.getElementById`, not `Document.getElementById` (notice the lower-case `d` - variables in JavaScript are case sensitive).

Secondly, where is `str` defined? In the `showUser` function you check to see if it's an empty string, but if it's not defined that's going to throw a `ReferenceError`.

Aside from that, it appears you never delcare the `xmlhttp` variable, so it will leak into the global scope, which is bad practice. You should declare every variable with the `var` keyword at the top of it's scope.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I have changed to lowercase, and gotten rid of this code:

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I have changed from 'D' to 'd' and gotten rid of the empty str check (this was leftover code from the example i was using) however the problem persists. Selecting the second drop down does not seem to work any magic.